# How to get date in EST

Tags: java, date

Please suggest a way to print a date in EST.

```
public Date convertToEST(Date date)
{
     // some code here
}
```

If I pass in a date in IST, the method should return that date in EST.

Comment: as they say — java is to javascript as car is to carpet

Comment: i need that to be done injava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing time zones in java

```
public class TimeZoneSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        // I am in IST time Zone (Its ID is Asia/Calcutta or ITS)
        System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
        // I get Indian Time printed
        System.out.println(new Date());
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        // I am setting the time zone to China
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CTT"));
        // Now my default time zone is in China
        System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
        // I get Chian Time printed
        System.out.println(new Date());
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        // I am setting the time zone to EST
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        // Now my default time zone is in EST
        System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
        // I get Eastern Time printed
        System.out.println(new Date());

    }

}
```

console output

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
Wed Dec 26 10:22:25 IST 2012
-------------------
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="CTT",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=19,lastRule=null]
Wed Dec 26 12:52:25 CST 2012
-------------------
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="EST",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
Tue Dec 25 23:52:25 EST 2012
```

Comment: this what i expected thanks a lot buddy :) This helped me a lot

Comment: -04:00 = PRT (-4a Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Time). Ref this link on [different time zone](http://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/InfoDocument/2908587.html)

Comment: `GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")).getTime()` does not work! Any ideas?

Comment: EST time is coming one hour less. Current est time is 9.22 am may 19. But it is printing one hour less in my console. Probably daylight time issue. How to overcome this? any idea?

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate     // Avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes. 
    .toInstant()   // Convert from legacy class to modern class `Instant`, always in UTC by definition.
    .atZone(       // Adjust into a time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
        ZoneId.of( “America/New_York” )  // Never use “EST”/“IST” pseudo-zones. Use proper continent/region names. 
    )              // Yields a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## Use `Instant`, not `Date`

The other Answers use troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Those were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Forget about `java.util.Date`, a poorly-designed mess of a class.

> If I pass in a date in IST,

**Don’t!**

Learn to think, work, exchange, and log in UTC values. Forget about your own parochial time zone while on the job as programmer or administrator. Think of UTC as the *One True Time*, all other zones are but mere variations.

The building block in java.time is `Instant` class. This class represents a moment, a point on the timeline in UTC. Internally represented as a count of seconds plus nanoseconds since the start of 1970 in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Such `Instant` objects are what you should be passing around your code, generally speaking. Adjust into a time zone only when required by your business logic or user-interface.

Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones seen frequently in the media, such as “IST” or “EST”. Instead, use proper time zone names defined as `continent/region` such as `Europe/Paris` or `Asia/Kolkata` or `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/New_York” ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you must serialize to text to exchange date-time values, use the standard ISO 8601 formats. These are used by default in java.time `toString` and `parse` methods.

To generate Strings in other formats, see the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

To inter-operate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, call on new conversion methods added to the old classes.

A `Date` represents a moment in UTC, and so it maps directly to `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

And…

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

The legacy `GregorianCalendar` maps to the modern `ZonedDateTime`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: > "Never use “EST”/“IST” pseudo-zones"
why?

Comment: @Samir Because they are not real time zone names. And they are not standardized. And they are not unique: Does `IST` mean  *Irish Standard Time* or *India Standard Time*? Yes, both. And both are invalid when Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect.  Instead use `Europe/Dublin` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

Answer (score 6):

You need the following

```
Date date = new Date();  

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));  

// Prints the date in the EST timezone  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

To make return the method a `Date` object, you will need as shown below

```
public static Date convertToEST(Date date) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    return formatter.parse((formatter.format(date)));
}
```

Javadoc- [`DateFormat.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29), [`DateFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: in my console am still getting it as IST dude wats the prob ?

Comment: when i print just as String "formatter.format(date)" it is fine am getting it in EST. but, when i print system.out.println(formatter.parse(formatter.format(date)))); am getting it as IST

Comment: i think i should change my workstation(PC) time zone to EST am getting as expected but i want do this without changing my workstation time zone

Comment: `GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")).getTime()` does not work. Any idea?

Comment: This code does not return the correct EST time. I tried it

Answer (score 4):

The idea of "the method should return that date in EST" is wrong. Date is only a holder of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. It has nothing to do with the time zone.

Comment: system.out.println(new Date()); i get something like a MMM dd HH:mm:ss IST yyyy i just want this in EST

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat requiredDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a zzz, EEE MMMM dd,yyyy");
requiredDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
String date = requiredDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
```

Console Output: 06:25 AM EST, Tue February 13,2018

Comment: These troublesome confusing date-time classes are obsolete, supplanted by the *java.time* classes years ago. Their use is ill-advised in 2018.

Comment: @BasilBourque Even in 2020, Android SDK still didn't get the java.time package added in Java 8. It's only present on Nougat and later, while most apps still have to support Lollipop at the least.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati No, your comment is not up-to-date. The API desugaring ability in latest Android tools bring a subset of *java.time* and other features to older Android versions before 26. See links at end of [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48772823/642706) on this page. There is no need to ever again use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.